# How to recursively change JS Object/JSON values at any level?

Tags: javascript, json, nested, key

**Please note that the structure I've provided is just an example but can be anything**.

The main goal is to change the keys' values of my choice recursively, at any level, to a value of my choice.

Here's the example for clarification:

```
    var items = {
      price: 10,
      child: {
        price: 20, 
         child: {
           price: 10
         }
      },
      child2: {
        price: 40,
        child: {
          price: 50,
          child: [{ price: 30 }, { price: 40 }]
        }
      }
    };
```

Given this, how would you change all prices to 0?

Comment: I voted to close this question as too broad, because it just appears to be a data dump with a request for someone else to do the work of the data transformation on the poster's behalf.  There does not appear to be any code to troubleshoot here.

Comment: I mainly wanted to know if there was a library function that would do that, but library questions are also downvoted (what isn't downvoted on Stack Overflow though). I've searched Google and the solution I was heading to was too complex. By asking here I got a simple answer in less than 5 minutes... isn't that the point?

Comment: Please note that I did not downvote the question, but I did nominate the question for closure.  In my opinion, the question didn't really offer any evidence that any effort was made to solve the problem before a data dump was put out.  Others obviously feel differently, as is evidenced by the answers provided.  While it is nice that an answer was given that probably points you in the right direction, I just don't feel that the question has a long term positive use for others in the future. (which is the bedrock of the site, being a QA repository).

Comment: I just wanted to make the question as clear and uncluttered as possible. I think anybody who wants to solve the same problem will be happy to find those answers, as their efforts can potentially lead them here. What I don't understand is how the research I've done beforehand is relevant for long-term effect? They might just want to do the same thing, land here, have an answer, and be on their way (since it's a very general scenario and not just a data dump specific to my needs).

Comment: The only thing I can really say to explain this is that Close Votes and Upvotes/Downvotes are all very opinionated, and every person has their own opinion on the matter, and many times opinions are based on emotion.  Any time your question **feels like** you are "punting" your work off onto others, or not really showing any effort, you are much more likely to get negative responses.  In the help guide [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), one of the very first things is the concept of showing not just what's wrong, but what **hasn't worked**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general idea:

```js
function f(obj, prop, val){
  if (typeof obj == 'object'){
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
      obj[prop] = val;
      
    for (let i in obj)
      f(obj[i], prop, val);
  }
}

var items = {
  price: 10,
  child: {
    price: 20, 
     child: {
       price: 10
     }
  },
  child2: {
    price: 40,
    child: {
      price: 50,
      child: [{ price: 30 }, { price: 40 }]
    }
  }
};

f(items, 'price', 0);

console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop recursively and check for the key `price`.

```js
var items = {  price: 10,  child: {    price: 20,    child: {      price: 10    }  },  child2: {    price: 40,    child: {      price: 50,      child: [{        price: 30      }, {        price: 40      }] }  }};

function loop(obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object') return;
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((k) => {
    if (k === 'price') obj[k] = 0;
    else loop(obj[k]);
  });
}

loop(items);

console.log(items)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Seems to fail for `loop([1,2,'price'])`

Comment: @גלעדברקן yes, however, that's out of scope.

Comment: How is it out of scope? I just fed it data :)

Comment: @גלעדברקן out of scope according to the question's body

Comment: Quote from the question: "the structure I've provided is just an example but it can be anything" :)